# Install Civ 5 mod on Linux

Tags: steam, civilization-5, mods, linux

Playing Portugal, I'd really like to have the [Trade Opportunities](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=453027) mod. But how do I install it on a Linux system? I could not find it in the mod hub, as suggested by the link.

Answer (score -3):

I found some instructions here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/0/540744299996631016/ or maybe better is here: http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=528742

Comment: could you summarize what's in the link as you can not guarantee that the link will always be there